# To acquire butter on a knife for the purpose of spreading?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is probably a really common word and I'm having a moment, but it occurred to me the other day that I can't think of the verb that describes the action of sweeping a knife across a pat of butter, which has the effect of scraping butter from the pat onto the knife. It's kind of the opposite of "spreading"; i.e., the action to deposit butter from the knife to the bread/toast/whatever.

"Scraping", I suppose, is close...but it doesn't feel right. Intuitively, I feel like scraping involves a fair amount of effort to remove the surface layer, which is usually hard, contrary to the properties of butter at room temperature. "Peeling" or "paring", perhaps, but again I'm not convinced: butter doesn't have a peel and paring is more of a cutting action. The artefact of the process is a "curl of butter", so maybe "curling", but I've never heard that used in this way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Shave** the butter using a butter knife.

From  *[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=shave%20definition&oq=shave%20def&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i15i22i30l4j0i10i15i22i30j0i22i30l3.166976210j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* (via Google)

> cut (a thin slice or slices) from the surface of something.
> "scrape a large sharp knife across the surface, shaving off rolls of very fine chocolate"

Comment: A good word if the butter is still firm or hard.

Comment: I like "shave"; I'm torn between this and "skim". I guess it depends on how hard the butter is!

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but I keep my butter on the counter-top and in the summertime especially, it is quite soft.

Comment: In the hottest months of summer butter turns almost runny if it's kept outside the fridge for an extended period. I live in N. Italy and fair to say it's been very very hot recently. :)

Answer (score 22):

You ***load*** the knife with butter before spreading it on the bread.

Comment: As with a palette knife, good answer.

Comment: This makes sense if one thinks of bread as a butter-delivery platform.

Comment: "Load" is good, but it's quite general. For example, one could load a knife with butter by carving a small chunk out of the pat, then stabbing said chunk so it adheres to the knife. Loading achieved, but probably not what one had in mind.

Comment: @Xophmeister load is *technically* correct, but colloquially is incorrect.  "Scrape" or "cut" are the correct verbs, depending on the source of the butter.

Comment: Hmpf, I can't quite get my mind off "*up*loading" butter with a knife and "*down*loading" it onto bread. (tbc: not disrespecting the answer)

Answer (score 17):

If the requirement for a thin curl is removed, **scoop** works, and is easily understood, even though a knife is not a a scoop.

> I scooped up a generous portion of butter with my knife and spread it over my toast.

[An interesting reddit discussion on the related subject of peanut butter](https://www.reddit.com/r/INTP/comments/66fuxc/word_for_using_a_knife_to_get_peanut_butter/)

Comment: I'm not convinced by "scoop". I agree it's easily understood, but if one were to ask "Could you scoop me some butter?" I wouldn't be surprised if you reached for a spoon.

Comment: @Xophmeister neither would I, but if a spoon were unavailable and all I had was a knife, I would not refuse to scoop the butter.

Comment: I think, in your example, "curl" itself might work. "I curled some butter from the pat onto my knife..."

Comment: [The Exact Instructions Challenge video has the girl use ‘scoop’](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDA3_5982h8&t=77), so it seems it’s not only easy to understand, but also pretty idiomatic (= easy to come up with).

Answer (score 9):

Until relatively recently with the advent of refrigeration, butter was soft, so there's not going to be a word that goes back through the centuries referring specifically and narrowly to the scraping action with the knife that you describe, though the verb **skim** might do:

> He broke into the empty house and went back to the kitchen. He reached into the fridge and took out a tub of butter, setting it on the kitchen counter. He put a slice of bread in the toaster. When the bread popped up, he **skimmed** a curl of butter from the tub and spread it across the surface, trying not to crush the toast. He wondered how so many Americans could eat the terrible air-filled stuff. A slice of it fresh from the plastic bag could be squeezed down into a ball the size of a shooter marble.

Comment: Is that a quote? Where did you find this use of *skimmed*? Quotes need to be referenced.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  No, Andrew, it is not a quotation. It is my rant against American white bread.

Comment: Used to do that with 'Wonderloaf' in the 60's. Made for great fun seeing if the seagulls were fast enough to catch it when thrown in the air; much harder than regular chunks of bread. If you want to see the ultimate in compressible bread, try Japan.

Comment: It should be made clear within the answer that the example of possible use of the term is not an actual quotation from an independently existing text, as that may be relevant in assessing the answer.

Comment: @jsw29: Consider it an actual use, since I'm not a bot.  But seriously, I thought I made clear that there is no word that specifically means"to skim a little bit of butter from the surface of a larger amount of butter" and that **skim** "might do", that is, might be well understood (given its similar uses in culinary contexts and its other meanings related to passing lightly over something).

Comment: In lieu of any evidence of a word that is actually intended for this usage, this is the first suggested word that actually feels right, regardless of quibbles about the quotation.

Comment: I like "skim"; I'm torn between this and "shave". I guess it depends on how hard the butter is!

Comment: And on whether you want any hint of beard stubble or other hair in your butter.

Comment: @Xophmeister To me "shave" suggests a sharp implement (as you generally need for chocolate but not for butter).

Comment: @Tim, when you say 'I thought I made clear', who exactly is 'I'? This answer was posted by TimR, not by you. If you are, in fact, the same person as TimR, you may wish to merge the two accounts.

Comment: @jsw29:  My Chromebook and my Windows 10 PC (and my Windows 7 PC before that) are all on separate accounts. I have an account on ELL created back under the Windows 7 hardware (Tᴚoɯɐuo).  I will look into the process of merging them.

Answer (score 4):

"Scoop up" works for me. Although the knife is not scoop-shaped, you alter the angle of the blade in the soft butter to scoop the butter onto the blade. Specialist butter spreading knives have a curved (but not dished) shape to facilitate the scooping action. From [this](https://www.knivesandtools.com/en/ct/butter-knives.htm) advertisement:

> Butter knives: your breakfast's finishing touch Butter knives are
> specifically designed to spread butter or other spreads on your
> sandwich, baguette, toast or crackers. Usually, these knives have a
> round tip to allow you to **scoop up** the spread from its container.

Comment: This answer is very similar to the one by @barbecue. It is reasonable to assume that they were composed independently, as they appeared only a few minutes from each other. It may nevertheless be a good idea to edit this (slightly later) answer to bring out any difference that there might be between the two (how important is *up* in *scoop up*?).

Answer (score 0):

It may not suit your purposes, but "gather" is a good general cooking term. In this case you'd "Gather butter along the blade". Personally, I like this particularly because I feel it better connotates soft butter, as opposed to words such as "carve" and "shave".

Comment: Would you really say this when using a knife? It sounds unnatural to me. If you could provide examples from the web supporting this usage it would really strengthen your answer.

Answer (score -4):

**Butter**

We need to understand that the word "butter" can also be used as a verb, and the verb "to butter" has several common uses, including describing the action of buttering a sandwich, or buttering the knife.

> : to spread with or as if with butter

[Merriam-Webester](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butter#:%7E:text=2%20of%202-,verb,or%20as%20if%20with%20butter)

Comment: But the question is asking about the preparatory action of putting butter on the knife, ready to butter the bread. You wouldn't *butter the knife.*

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Correct. But the act of "buttering", could also be applied to buttering the knife.

Comment: The question does actually say *The artefact of the process is a "curl of butter"* and the idea is **not** to butter the knife.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - correct, I just use the stick. But I butter things for work all the time. This answer certainly isn't *wrong*.... Title might as well be, *Buttering a knife for the purpose of spreading*... wait for it... *butter.* Honestly it'd be, *for the purpose of walking into another room with it or handing it to someone*. Who does that?

Comment: I think this is a cute poetic usage, but not common usage by any means.

Comment: @JohnStrachan The only context in which I could imagine someone might "butter the knife" would be *protecting the blade from corrosion* (though using oil or lard would probably both be more typical, and knives, unlike swords and such, generally didn't need dedicated treatment - they just got greasy enough from standard use).

Comment: You'd butter a knife if you didn't want anything to stick to it…or just cut brownies with a plastic knife.